# Disable IE security on Windows Server via PowerShell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

it happens all the time, I spin up a vm with windows server and I can't access the internet because of IE security.  Does anyone have a straight-forward PowerShell script for disabling IE security?

Comment: What do you want to disable? ESC? Protected Mode?

Comment: yes, IE ESC (here's a few more characters to allow me to post this comment????)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
function Disable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0
    Stop-Process -Name Explorer
    Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green
}
function Enable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1
    Stop-Process -Name Explorer
    Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been enabled." -ForegroundColor Green
}
function Disable-UserAccessControl {
    Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Value 00000000
    Write-Host "User Access Control (UAC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green    
}
```

drop this into a .ps1 file

then at the prompt type a period, a space and the path to the file
something like this:

```
[PS 1] . C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\YourPowerShellScript.ps1
```

Then you can call the command at the prompt:

```
[PS 1] Disable-InternetExplorerESC
```

Comment: Why are you stopping "Explorer", but not restarting it?

Comment: @wes2020 I stole this script from somewhere but my assumption is that stopping explorer only 'restarts' it. Explorer will start if it is stopped

Comment: In Windows Server 2012, this does not work for me. If you start IE after applying this, the trusted popups still appear; in Server Manager, the trusted feature shows "off" but if you click to the configuration both admin and user checkboxes still show "on".

Comment: @MaxVT The Rundll32 iesetup.dll settings [here](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/06/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-using-powershell.html) appear to have fixed things on Server 2012.

Answer (score 17):

The below modification has added -Force parameters to avoid any confirmations. I was prompted to do this when prompted to confirm that I wanted to end the "explorer" process..

```
function Disable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 0 -Force
    Stop-Process -Name Explorer -Force
    Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green
}
function Enable-InternetExplorerESC {
    $AdminKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    $UserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $AdminKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1 -Force
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserKey -Name "IsInstalled" -Value 1 -Force
    Stop-Process -Name Explorer -Force
    Write-Host "IE Enhanced Security Configuration (ESC) has been enabled." -ForegroundColor Green
}
function Disable-UserAccessControl {
    Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Value 00000000 -Force
    Write-Host "User Access Control (UAC) has been disabled." -ForegroundColor Green    
}
Disable-UserAccessControl
Disable-InternetExplorerESC
```

Comment: Guys, just export the registry key you need, toggling the setting in Server Manager for Enable and Disable and use the .reg files in PowerShell. Don't make this so hard...