# Why is AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe failing to install on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: installation, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

Running AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe on a windows server 2012 R2 instance (hosted in azure) fails with **0x80072f76 - Unspecified error**.

I read about [the known issue](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) where installing from a folder that also contains earlier beta vs web tooling MSI files can fail with **error 0x80091007 - The hash value is not correct**, but this is a different error (and I am installing from a different folder). According to the logs it looks like it may be a network issue. However, accessing the various go.microsoft.com URL's from chrome works fine. What gives?

Example log file snippet is below:

```
[0F00:0E4C][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i201: Planned package: SetupBlocked_Uninstall, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0F00:0E4C][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0F00:0E4C][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i300: Apply begin
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\.be\AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe'
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, version: 1.0.11117.0
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[062C:09C8][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i305: Verified acquired payload: SetupBlocked_Install at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SetupBlocked_Install, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0cb88b2b-7b82-3890-96ab-deccbbb3a255\SetupBlocked.exe.
[062C:09C8][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i305: Verified acquired payload: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2b825b3c-fe3f-3e14-b083-a41c0f8d1b22\Preparation.exe.
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:48]w343: Prompt for source of package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, path: C:\Users\srvc-teamcity\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache\aspnet5rc1\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:48]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:48]e000: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:48]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311' to: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64'
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:48]w343: Prompt for source of package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, path: C:\Users\srvc-teamcity\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache\aspnet5rc1\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:51]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:51]e000: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:51]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311' to: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64'
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:51]w343: Prompt for source of package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, path: C:\Users\srvc-teamcity\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache\aspnet5rc1\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:54]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:54]e000: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:54]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311' to: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64'
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:54]w343: Prompt for source of package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, path: C:\Users\srvc-teamcity\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache\aspnet5rc1\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:57]e000: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:57]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311' to: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64'
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:57]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690311' to working path: 'C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64'
[0F00:0FDC][2015-11-27T13:09:57]e313: Failed to acquire payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 to working path: C:\Users\SRVC-T~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80072f76.
[062C:09C8][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2b825b3c-fe3f-3e14-b083-a41c0f8d1b22\
[062C:09C8][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i351: Removing cached package: SetupBlocked_Install, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0cb88b2b-7b82-3890-96ab-deccbbb3a255\
[0F00:0E4C][2015-11-27T13:09:57]e000: Error 0x80072f76: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i352: Removing cached bundle: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\
[062C:0F18][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0F00:0E4C][2015-11-27T13:09:57]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80072f76, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a network error. By default, Windows 2012 R2 has IE Enhanced Security Configuration enabled. Disable IE Enhanced Security Configuration (for both Administrators and Users) using either the Server Manager [or powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9368555/304832) (or regedit), then run the exe again. It will succeed.

Comment: I followed danludwig's powershell link and the script to disable the IE ESC worked.  The powershell script is nice because it makes it easy to re-enable the ESC when done installing the update.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 I've got the same error. What does help for me:
In **Internet Explorer** click on the "Tools" button on the menu and select **Internet Options**. Select the “Advanced” tab and all the way toward the bottom you will see the option for "**warn if changing between secure and non secure mode**". **Uncheck** the option.